# Parse Intel hex file to extract only the data part in c language

Tags: c, parsing, hex, intel, lang

I am in search of a c program which parses Intel hex file format and extracts data part which can be further used for crc computation.

If anyone knows about it please post the program.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use the existing programs from online , but nothing is working as expected.

Comment: You mean this format? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX Seems simple enough. Have you tried to parse it yourself?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Plz see my code in the post.Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The "answers" you posted should be [edits] to the question.  Only post an answer to your own question if you've actually solved it.